# Is there a javascript loader which can limit the number of sockets to 1 or 2

Tags: javascript, connection, loader, limiting

I want to create a networked embedded device with an HTML5/JS one-page AJAX configuration application.

My problem is: browsers open too much connections nowadays, in my device the number of concurrent connections is maximum 4 with a TCP stack in hardware (please remember, it is an embedded device).

Any request through a socket > 4 seems to be lost, one has to press F5 until a combination of application and cache elements is sitting in the browser.

Now my initial idea was to use a js loader (with the favicon as a data-url) as index document, which in turn loads the rest of the application one by one (perhaps also with progress bar, but that would be luxury).

In theory this should assure that there is only one connection opened at one time.

All js loaders which I found are about parallelizing and making faster in broadband environments on clustered load-balanced webservers, but I need serializing and reliability on a tiny 8bit MCU with webserver.

Any hints or directions are appreciated!

Edit: I have to apologize for using "socket" and "connection" interchangeably, I did mean "connection" and changed the original post accordingly.

Comment: Why not include all resources inline in the HTML?

Comment: If it's an embedded device, what browser are you using? It seems like the limit should be imposed in the browser if possible. If you're using an open source browser that should be pretty easy

Comment: Are you basically asking if there's a JavaScript library that can control the number of connections my browser will attempt to open for multiple requests? Can you clump all the resources together into one or within the resource? Must you connect directly to the device?

Comment: You're the one who controls the sockets that are opened.  If you don't want something connected to a socket, don't put a listener on that port.  Unless you  mean connections.  If you mean that, then you may want to see what settings you can change in the web server regarding connections.  Also, some browsers limit the amount of connections going out, like IE (I believe less than current versions limited this to 2)

Comment: The Problem seems to be that there is no real limit any more:

Comment: The problem seems to be that there is no real limit on concurrent browser connections to one specific server any more: [this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/) is four years old, and it seems to have become worse (for my type of application).
I will look into completely inlining the application.

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @Peter: [Here's more current data.](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)  The limit is somewhere between 2 and 9 concurrent connections per server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to *reliably* limit the number of connections a browser makes to your server is by only requiring a single connection to load everything in your page.  In other words, everything must be inline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>MCU app</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:...">
<style>
    /* css here */
</style>
<script>
   // JS here
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Of course, watch out for `<img>` tags.

The other option I'd consider is hosting your HTML/JS/CSS/etc on a regular web server, and making only API calls to the embedded device.

For example, you'd open *mycoolembeddedapp.com* in your browser.  The app could ask for the embedded device's IP address, and then make AJAX calls to that IP using CORS.