# Set a limit for the browser for simultaneous TCP connections

Tags: javascript, ipad, http, tcp, safari

Is it possible to limit the number of single TCP connections to a web server in an HTML or JavaScript. A lot of browser open up to 8 connections per server to make loading faster. Is it possible to limit it somehow from the client side? The situation is that I have a web server that does not like a lot of simultaneous TCP connections.

- Is there a Java Script/HTML5 Solution Parameter or function
- Is there a way to reduce this on an IPad Safari browser
- They are only talking about a solution with inline Code:
  [Is there a javascript loader which can limit the number of sockets to 1 or 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906900/is-there-a-javascript-loader-which-can-limit-the-number-of-sockets-to-1-or-2)
  Is there another way? Something browser specific that could work in Safari?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a javascript loader which can limit the number of sockets to 1 or 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906900/is-there-a-javascript-loader-which-can-limit-the-number-of-sockets-to-1-or-2)

Comment: That is a clint-side setting that has to be made using the UI of the client browser (or other ways of editing its configuration). I think there is nothing you can do to change this setting from your page.

Comment: Do you know how this can be done on Safari/IPad?